# VBA For Each sum loop function returning 0

Tags: vba, function

I am relatively new to VBA, and have been struggling with making complex functions work. I am particularly stumped on this function I created, that works as a Sub but not as a Function. My function searches through each sheet in the workbook, finds a table that begins with "Budget*", and adds the cells in a column that is specified by the user (Right now it is activecell, but I want this to be an input for the function). The number of sheets is unknown, so it is impossible to try to write this function as an actual value of a cell. I even tried to create a separate function that called the sub, but that doesn't work either. When I use the function in the worksheet, all I get is a value of 0. Please help!

```
Private Sub IncomeSum()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ColumnNumber = ActiveCell.Column
IncomeMonthSum = 0

For Each WS In Sheets
    WS.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 255 Then Exit For
    If ActiveSheet.Index >= 4 Then

        For Each Tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
            If Tbl.Name Like "Budget*" Then
            TableName = Tbl.Name
            Exit For
            End If
        Next Tbl

    ColumnSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(TableName & "[[#All],[Column" & ColumnNumber & "]]"))
    IncomeMonthSum = IncomeMonthSum + ColumnSum
    End If
Next WS

Answer = MsgBox(IncomeMonthSum)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And here is the function I tried to have call the sub:

```
Function IncomeSum2()

IncomeSum
IncomeSum2 = IncomeMonthSum

End Function
```

I even stepped through the function above, and added watches for the values in the sub. I started my run through the code at the function, and watched it go through the sub, then back to the function. The watches showed that the sub was working, and that the values were correct, but as soon as the code came back to the Function from the Sub, suddenly the values came back zero.

Edit:

Thank you @DisplayName! Here is what I am really trying to go for, and it only returns a value of 0:

```
Function IncomeSum(Month)

ColumnNumber = Month.Column
IncomeMonthSum = 0

For Each WS In Sheets
    WS.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = 255 Then Exit For
    If ActiveSheet.Index >= 4 Then

        For Each Tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
            If Tbl.Name Like "Budget*" Then
            TableName = Tbl.Name
            Exit For
            End If
        Next Tbl

    ColumnSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(TableName & "[[#All],[Column" & ColumnNumber & "]]"))
    IncomeMonthSum = IncomeMonthSum + ColumnSum
    End If
Next WS

IncomeSum = IncomeMonthSum

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `IncomeSum2` is calling `IncomeSum` to modify the local variable `IncomeMonthSum`. As `IncomeMonthSum` is local, trying to access it from another sub/function returns 0, since that sub/function does not have access to that variable.

To get access to that variable, you can try declaring `IncomeMonthSum` as a `Public` variable at the start of the module, like:

```
Public IncomeMonthSum as Double
Sub IncomeSum ()
    '...
```

As stated in another answer, this is a "dirty" approach. You should try altering your code so that you can return the variable and pass it as an argument to another function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest & dirtiest solution:

```
Dim IncomeMonthSum As Long

Function IncomeSum2()

    IncomeSum
    IncomeSum2 = IncomeMonthSum

End Function
```

There are plenty of people, that would be against declaring module variables and using them and indeed it is a bad practice. But in your case, it is obvious that you are once calling `IncomeSum` and then trying to get the value in `IncomeMonthSum`, generated in the Sub `IncomeSum`. This is only possible if you declare teh `IncomeMonthSum` as a module variable. See this short example:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    TestMe2
    Debug.Print A
End Sub

Public Sub TestMe2()
    A = 5
End Sub
```

In it, you can notice, that `A` is a separate variable in `TestMe` and `TestMe2`. This is called "variable scope". As far as the scope of the variables is different, then the two `A`-s have nothing to do with each other.

---

The best way to do it, is to rewrite the code, thus returning `IncomeMonthSum` from the function.

Answer (score 0):

to have `Function IncomeSum2()` know about the value of `IncomeMonthSum` variable set inside `Private Sub IncomeSum()` you have to pass that variable bewteen them

change:

```
Private Sub IncomeSum()
```

to:

```
Private Sub IncomeSum(IncomeMonthSum) ' have 'IncomeSum() sub accept a parameter named 'IncomeMonthSum'
```

and change:

```
Function IncomeSum2()

    IncomeSum
    IncomeSum2 = IncomeMonthSum

End Function
```

to:

```
Function IncomeSum2()
    IncomeSum IncomeMonthSum ' call 'IncomeSum()' sub passing variable 'IncomeMonthSum' as its parameter
    IncomeSum2 = IncomeMonthSum ' return the value of 'IncomeMonthSum' as processed by 'IncomeSum' call above
End Function
```

Comment: It works! That's awesome! I'll be honest though, I don't know how it works. And although it works, when I enter the function into the workbook, it still comes back with a value of 0. Here is what I really want, because the function calling the sub is just a workaround (See my question edit)